# Convert PointF[] to CGPoint[]

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

The example code in the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/CoreGraphics.CGContext.AddLines/p/CoreGraphics.CGPoint[]/) for `CGContext.AddLines` does not compile for me.

```
ctxt.AddLines (new PointF[] {
    new PointF (30, 30),
    new PointF (60, 30),
    new PointF (40, 40)
});
```

The error is

> cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.PointF[]' to 'CoreGraphics.CGPoint[]'

I do notice that this works:

```
  public void AddStraightLine(PointF start, PointF end)
  {
     var path = new CGPath();

     path.AddLines(new CGPoint[]
     {
        start,
        end
     });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is a little outdated you will have to switch it to use `CoreGraphics.CGPoint`, which is the newest and only overload, instead of `System.Drawing.PointF`. This is the result of the required switch to iOS [Unified API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/unified/updating-ios-apps).

The corresponding unified change for iOS ported from the docs would look something like this:

```
using (var ctxt = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
{
    var startingPoint = new CGPoint(20, 20);
    ctxt.MoveTo(startingPoint.X, startingPoint.Y);
    ctxt.SetStrokeColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);
    var sz = new CGSize(2, 2);
    Func<CGPoint, CGPoint> offset = (CGPoint pt) => new CGPoint(pt.X - 1, pt.Y - 1);
    ctxt.AddEllipseInRect(new CGRect(offset(startingPoint), sz));

    ctxt.AddLines(new CGPoint[]
    {
        new CGPoint (30, 30),
        new CGPoint (60, 30),
        new CGPoint (40, 40)
    });

    ctxt.StrokePath();
}
```

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. Your link led me to this one, which describes exactly what I'm seeing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/nativetypes

Comment: As a side note, are there any cross-platform considerations with this change, since the old one is in `System.Drawing` and the new in `CoreGraphics`?

Comment: these APIs are specifically for iOS and MacOS, so cross platform isn't really a consideration

Comment: Jason is correct and I updated my answer to show what the documentation would be switched to the unified api.

Comment: What I mean is, consider the hypothetical .NET Standard interface method `PointF ConvertToPixels(PointF point, IMap bounds);` -- that library can't update to Unified, since it doesn't reference Xamarin.iOS. (I made `IMap`)

Comment: You could switch it over to take in a `ConvertToPixels(double x, double y, IMap bounds);` and then on the corresponding platform create whatever kind of point you need from the x and y values.